# Loading the Table little by little in chunks

Tags: c#, linq

To not run out of memory by brining in the whole table at ones, I am doing in it chunks of `LOAD_SIZE` records.
Here is how I am doing it, I feel like there are some indexes that are off by one record? and possible performance improvements that I can do in
So I wanted to have your opinion on this approach.

```
        int totalCount = repo.Context.Employees.Count();
        int startRow = 0;
        while (startRow <= totalCount)
        {
            repo.PaginateEmployees(startRow, LOAD_SIZE);
            startRow = startRow + LOAD_SIZE ;
        }

    public List<EmpsSummary> PaginateEmployees(int startRow, int loadSize)
    {
        var query = (from p in this.Context.Employees
                     .Skip(startRow).Take(loadSize)
            select new EmpsSummary
            {
                FirstName =  p.FirstName,
                LastName =  p.LastName,
                Phone = p.Phone
            });

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: One comment: `while (startRow <= totalCount)` should use `<`. Also, is this for loading a grid of data or are you using these chunks for something else?

Comment: I'm not sure you gain much by doing it this way... the .NET SQL framework is already lazy -- but you lose that when you use `Take`.  If we had more context about how you are using this data we might be able to show you a much simpler solution that leverages the built in memory management of .NET

Comment: I have a list of people that I want to insert in DB, but I don't want to overwrite the ones that are already in DB. The criteria that says one person is already in DB for me is combination of his name and phone. So I am gonna pull in all the people in DB, compare it to the list I have and eliminate the ones that are already there.

Comment: It is also not clear at all how this is working in your example -- you never make use of the returned list from `PaginateEmployees`  What do you do with this list?  write it to a file?  If that is all you did then there is a better way. (as an example)

Comment: @Hogan thanks, I added a comment explaining the scenario in more details.

Comment: @Hogan Also can you please explain this more too? " but you lose that when you use Take"

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack - I can't explain it easily. Read up on how lazy loading works in Linq.  Basically, internally Linq will only load stuff in memory when you need it.  But certain functions (like ToList() and Take()) "break" the lazy part... that is, they force the memory load at that sequential point.

Comment: [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062.aspx) is still lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how Linq works (lazy loading and has compares), if you formulate your statements right it will manage memory much better than you will be able.

From your comments (which should be added to the question) I offer this solution which should manage memory for you just fine.

**This example code is not intended to compile -- it is given as an example**

```
// insert list
List<EmpsSummary> insertList; 
// add stuff to insertList

List<EmpsSummary> filteredList = insertList.Except(this.Context.Employees);
```

This assumes that `this.Context.Employees` is of type EmpsSummary.  If it isn't you have to cast it to the correct type.

Also you will need to be able to compare EmpsSummary.  To do so create this IEquitable like this:

**This example code is not intended to compile -- it is given as an example**

```
public class EmpsSummary : IEquatable<EmpsSummary>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(EmpsSummary other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return FirstName.Equals(other.FirstName) &&
               LastName.Equals(other.LastName) &&
               Phone.Equals(other.Phone);
    }


    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashProductFirstName  = FirstName == null ? 0 : FirstName.GetHashCode();

        int hashProductLastName = LastName == null ? 0 : LastName.GetHashCode();

        int hashProductPhone = Phone == null ? 0 : Phone.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code 
        return hashProductFirstName  ^ hashProductLastName  ^ hashProductPhone;
    }
}
```

Comment: InsertList is all the employees I have on my hand, that still I don't know which ones should I really insert in DB. But what is "filteredList"?.. plus: someone down voted your answer, it wasn't me :)

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack - filtered list is the the insert list less the items that already are in the database.  These are the new ones to insert.

Comment: Your `filteredList` line won't compile and your `IEquatable` implementation won't translate to the database.